# Gitlab CI services are stopped after bizzar psql call

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab-ci

I am trying to use services in gitlab ci, namely, postgres. Anyway, postgres service doesn't seem to be running, although I just copied what is there in Gitlab CI docs. In logs, after service logs that it started, some psql command (I don't know where it came from) gives an name resolution error. If I am doing something wrong here, what is the way to run postgres service in gitlab-ci?

Below are `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and logs:

*`.gitlab-ci.yml`*

```
image: ubuntu

services:
  - name: postgres:12.2-alpine
    alias: postgres

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: badr 
  POSTGRES_USER: badr 
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: badr
  PGHOST: postgres
  POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust

stages:
  - test

test db:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - until (echo > /dev/tcp/postgres/5432) >/dev/null 2>&1;do >&2 echo "service not ready...sleeping";sleep 5;done
  script: 
    - echo "connected to...$PGHOST"
    - sleep 10
```

`logs`

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.2.0-rc2 (45f2b4ec)
  on docker-auto-scale fa6cab46
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:55
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu ...
Starting service postgres:12.2-alpine ...
Pulling docker image postgres:12.2-alpine ...
Using docker image sha256:ae192c4d3adaebbbf2f023e1e50eaadfabccb6b08c855ac13d6ce2232381a58a for postgres:12.2-alpine ...
WARNING: Service postgres:12.2-alpine is already created. Ignoring.
Waiting for services to be up and running...
*** WARNING: Service runner-fa6cab46-project-14794655-concurrent-0-f52b350b86ad38db-postgres-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
service "runner-fa6cab46-project-14794655-concurrent-0-f52b350b86ad38db-postgres-0-wait-for-service" timeout
Health check container logs:
Service container logs:
2020-07-31T09:15:00.377204181Z ********************************************************************************
2020-07-31T09:15:00.377254629Z WARNING: POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD has been set to "trust". This will allow
2020-07-31T09:15:00.377259167Z          anyone with access to the Postgres port to access your database without
2020-07-31T09:15:00.377262471Z          a password, even if POSTGRES_PASSWORD is set. See PostgreSQL
2020-07-31T09:15:00.377265670Z          documentation about "trust":
2020-07-31T09:15:00.377269181Z          https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
2020-07-31T09:15:00.377272282Z          In Docker's default configuration, this is effectively any other
2020-07-31T09:15:00.377276152Z          container on the same system.
2020-07-31T09:15:00.377295876Z 
2020-07-31T09:15:00.377299453Z          It is not recommended to use POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust. Replace
2020-07-31T09:15:00.377302412Z          it with "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" instead to set a password in
2020-07-31T09:15:00.377305641Z          "docker run".
2020-07-31T09:15:00.377308656Z ********************************************************************************
2020-07-31T09:15:00.404620899Z The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
2020-07-31T09:15:00.406021814Z This user must also own the server process.
2020-07-31T09:15:00.406074886Z 
2020-07-31T09:15:00.406083517Z The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
2020-07-31T09:15:00.406087263Z The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
2020-07-31T09:15:00.406090884Z The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
2020-07-31T09:15:00.406094281Z 
2020-07-31T09:15:00.406097490Z Data page checksums are disabled.
2020-07-31T09:15:00.406101511Z 
2020-07-31T09:15:00.406197662Z fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
2020-07-31T09:15:00.406858429Z creating subdirectories ... ok
2020-07-31T09:15:00.407274720Z selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
2020-07-31T09:15:00.428414929Z selecting default max_connections ... 100
2020-07-31T09:15:00.506801199Z selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
2020-07-31T09:15:00.689382376Z selecting default time zone ... UTC
2020-07-31T09:15:00.695744690Z creating configuration files ... ok
2020-07-31T09:15:01.009439741Z running bootstrap script ... ok
2020-07-31T09:15:01.355673765Z sh: locale: not found
2020-07-31T09:15:01.355836607Z 2020-07-31 09:15:01.355 UTC [30] WARNING:  no usable system locales were found
2020-07-31T09:15:01.784080826Z performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
2020-07-31T09:15:02.416545146Z syncing data to disk ... ok
2020-07-31T09:15:02.416652656Z 
2020-07-31T09:15:02.416854775Z initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
2020-07-31T09:15:02.416911707Z You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
2020-07-31T09:15:02.416917642Z --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
2020-07-31T09:15:02.416962149Z 
2020-07-31T09:15:02.416967325Z Success. You can now start the database server using:
2020-07-31T09:15:02.416970415Z 
2020-07-31T09:15:02.416990907Z     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
2020-07-31T09:15:02.416995097Z 
2020-07-31T09:15:02.440378884Z waiting for server to start....2020-07-31 09:15:02.440 UTC [35] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 9.2.0) 9.2.0, 64-bit
2020-07-31T09:15:02.442773414Z 2020-07-31 09:15:02.442 UTC [35] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-07-31T09:15:02.461804500Z 2020-07-31 09:15:02.461 UTC [36] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-07-31 09:15:01 UTC
2020-07-31T09:15:02.465323529Z 2020-07-31 09:15:02.465 UTC [35] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-07-31T09:15:02.524643142Z  done
2020-07-31T09:15:02.524766601Z server started
2020-07-31T09:15:02.537508874Z psql: error: could not connect to server: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name does not resolve
*********
Pulling docker image ubuntu ...
Using docker image sha256:1e4467b07108685c38297025797890f0492c4ec509212e2e4b4822d367fe6bc8 for ubuntu ...
Preparing environment
00:02
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/badrmoh/cicdtest/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 604433de as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ until (echo > /dev/tcp/postgres/5432) >/dev/null 2>&1;do >&2 echo "service not ready...sleeping";sleep 5;done
service not ready...sleeping
service not ready...sleeping
service not ready...sleeping
service not ready...sleeping
service not ready...sleeping
service not ready...sleeping
```

`gitlab-runner`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in `PGHOST` variable. It seems it is used internally by postgres container that is why it fails to start.
The solution is to set `PGHOST` in `script` directive:

```
image: ubuntu

services:
  - name: postgres:9
    alias: postgres

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: badr 
  POSTGRES_USER: badr 
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: badr
  POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust

stages:
  - test
test db:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - export PGHOST=postgres
    - until (echo > /dev/tcp/$PGHOST/5432) >/dev/null 2>&1;do >&2 echo "service $PGHOST not ready...sleeping";sleep 5;done
  script: 
    - echo "connected to...$PGHOST"
    - sleep 10
```

Note: You can't use variables directive within jobs in this case since it seems to be populated before even starting services itself.